# JavaScript: missing logic when array iterate for missing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to fill blank values when no data available for particular months. Here is plunker.. http://plnkr.co/edit/f0IklkUfX8tkRZrn2enx?p=preview

```
$scope.year = [
{"month":"mar", "val":"23"},
{"month":"feb", "val":"45"},
{"month":"jan", "val":"56"}   
];

var total = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];


for(var i=0; i<total.length; i++){

if($scope.year[i].month === undefined){ //logic here to see absent month.

        $scope.year.push(
        {
            "month":total[i],
            "val":"0" 
        })
    }
}
```

I have created array of default total months items for compare each month item from expected object, if the item is absent in expected object, need to create empty item or with value "0" in expected object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like following

**Js Update**

```
var year = [
{"month":"mar", "val":"23"},
{"month":"feb", "val":"45"},
{"month":"jan", "val":"56"}   
];

var total = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];


// Current months array
var currentMonth = [];
angular.forEach(year, function(item){
currentMonth.push(item.month); 
});

// iterating over months
for(var i=0; i<total.length; i++){
  //$scope.year = [];

// checking if month is absent
if(currentMonth.indexOf(total[i]) === -1){ //logic here to see absent month.

        year.push(
        {
            "month":total[i],
            "val":"0",
            "order" : i
        })
    } else {
     year[currentMonth.indexOf(total[i])].order = i;    // adding order
}
} 

$scope.year = year;
```

**Markup**

```
 <!-- Order by new property order -->
 <td ng-repeat="item in year | orderBy: 'order'">
            {{item.val}}
          </td>
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/km6jLQv8wxm1XP8QCxvV?p=preview

Comment: But one thing you can observer the moths vales are not mapped properly. like jan getting "23" instead of "56"... ans others also...

Answer (score 0):

year[i] is undefined, so you try get field of object that don't exist. 
try it  "if($scope.year[i] === undefined)"

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using `orderBy` won't work based on `month` because you aren't looking for an alphabetical sort.

Following creates array of months that exist in the data. Then it loops over all months in year and adds missing data. Finally sort the data based on months indexing

```
 // create array of months available in data
  var availableMonths = $scope.year.map(function(item){
    return item.month;
  });

  // loop over all months and if it doesn't exist in data add it
  total.forEach(function(mo){        
    if(availableMonths.indexOf(mo) ===-1 ){
      $scope.year.push({"month":mo, "val":"0" })
    }
  });

  // sort data using index of months
  $scope.year.sort(function(a,b){
    return total.indexOf(a.month) > total.indexOf(b.month);
  });
```

remove the `orderBy` filter in html since data is already sorted

Steps 2 & 3 above could actually be combined to `splice()` the array so final order is correct but for ease of understanding I left them as separate operations

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/23kBN6wSxPQUdQzJtUs9?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

> ```
> $scope.year = [
>
> {"month":"jan", "val":"56"},
> {"month":"feb", "val":"45"},
> {"month":"mar", "val":"23"}
>
> ];
>
> var total = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
>
>
> for(var i=0; i<total.length; i++){
>
> if(!$scope.year[i] || $scope.year[i].month === undefined){
>
>         $scope.year.push(
>         {
>             "month":total[i],
>             "val":"0" 
>         })
>     }
> }
> ```